# Convergence of the sequence $\alpha_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} + \dots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to determine the convergence of this sequence?
$$\alpha_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+ \dots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}$$

I was trying to show first that the sequence has a monotony with
$$\alpha_{n+1}-\alpha_n$$
but I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: Can you find close upper and lower bounds for the terms in the sum $\alpha_n$?

Comment: I think i can show that $$\alpha_n < 1$$
but then aren't I supposed to show that the sequence also has a monotony? Or I am missing something here?

Comment: If you can also show that $\alpha_n > 1-b_n$, where $b_n\to 0$, then you'd be done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the sandwich theorem,

$$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\leq \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2}}=1$$

it is then clear to see that the limit is $1$.